# Javascript - sanitize specific html element

Tags: javascript, html

First of all, i have a return from API in a form of html. This will be used in my jqgrid. The sample return would be like this
Example name for my object is `obj`. Then `obj.something` is below.

```
<div title="custom_title">
    <div id="upper">
         data from somewhere and this is the part that sometimes need to be sanitized without affecting the other tags
    </div>

</div>
```

What i tried so far was trying to do this:
    var esc = $('');
    then did do this: `esc.text(obj.something).html();` but it sanitize all of it. 
Is there anything that i may not know on how to sanitize purely on javascript?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the API yours and something you can change? Returning unsanitized output wrapped in HTML is really something you should avoid.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i did sanitizing in the api. It is actually using that data from the api then giving it to another grid

Comment: Then why do you need to do sanitizing again on the client side if it's already sanitized by the API?

Comment: because scripts still get executed when adding that data to another grid

Comment: What scripts? If it's possible to inject scripts to the output, the API has failed to sanitize it correctly and you should fix *that* instead.

Comment: @elL You have control over the API, I'm I reading the comments correctly here, then my answer is not really necessary. If not, it's one way of accessing the content before it's loaded on the page.

Comment: @Juhana what i meant for the script was the unsanitize data. It is like this:
From the api(sanitized), it goes to one jqgrid.  Then i have a function that adds that data from jqgrid1 to jqgrid2.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation you can use [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify)

> DOMPurify sanitizes HTML and prevents XSS attacks. You can feed DOMPurify with string full of dirty HTML and it will return a string with clean HTML. DOMPurify will strip out everything that contains dangerous HTML and thereby prevent XSS attacks and other nastiness.

Answer (score -1):

Agreeing here with @Juhana: "*Returning unsanitized output wrapped in HTML is really something you should avoid.*" However if not and you want to control and sanitize the DOM you could do this in plain JS:

```js
obj = {};
obj.something = '<div title="custom_title"><div id="upper">data from somewhere and this is the part that sometimes need to be sanitized without affecting the other tags</div></div>';
         
var container = document.createElement("div"); //create an element in memory
container.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', obj.something); //serialize the HTML string into the structure.

   container.querySelector("#upper").innerHTML = ""; //empty the element, removing the data in it. (or do something else with it, like stripping all the a elements that do not start with http(s).

console.log(container)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It renders the HTML obj into a in memory element, than you can perform DOM manipulation on it and remove the content of the div with the id `upper`. When done insert the content of the container div into your grid.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but note that this removes the content rather than sanitizing it.

Comment: @RickHitchcock, Strictly that's what the OP is doing in his example, only for the entire HTML string. However the last can be omitted from the solution, the answer is really about serializing the HTML into an element and than use DOM manipulation to do your sanitizing.

Comment: True that the OP removes all the content.  However, note the word "sometimes":  "data from somewhere and this is the part that *sometimes* need to be sanitized without affecting the other tags."  If there are no tags or XSS injections in this string, there's nothing to sanitize.  In any case, the OP can respond to this as needed.